# intel_do_flush_locked failed Input/Output error

Tags: kubuntu, intel, opengl

Sometimes while running apps using OpenGL, the following message comes in the command line where I run the app. I have a Sandy Bridge integrated graphics card (the same as in the bug reports)

```
intel_do_flush_locked failed: Input/output error
```

Running any subsequent OpenGL apps fail with the same error.
Also this is displayed in the system log

```
[ 7730.683403] [drm:i915_wait_request] *ERROR* i915_wait_request returns -11 (awaiting 1322416 at 1322415, next 1322417)
```

I have seen many bugs about this but none of them seem to have a solution.
Is there any workaround for this (apart from disabling OpenGL)?

Answer (score 10):

Try `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 ./yourprogram`

Comment: This is a work-around at best.

Comment: What is the reason of the error and what does this solution exactly do?

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to fixed the issue for me:

```
export hiz=false
export INTEL_HIZ=0
export INTEL_SEPARATE_STENCIL=0
```

If it doesn't help try

```
sudo intel_reg_write 0x2120 0x1206800
```

[Source](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48508).

Comment: I've changed my computer; so I can't test it but I'm upvoting.

Comment: @RamchandraApte I think You shouldn't than.

Comment: Doesn't help. Anything else to try?

Comment: According to the source of this fix, this helps only with kernels before 3.3, after that the kernel fixes the problem. Did not help me, but I only get the `intel_do_flush_locked failed` message, not the syslog entry.