# Minecraft won't launch due to error in launcher

Tags: xubuntu, games, minecraft

Today Minecraft stopped working and I could not launch it.
Here is the launcher:

```
[09:00:11] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user:<br/>
[09:00:11] [Client thread/INFO]: (Session ID is token:5b4403d3d9404ccd84f24eb3d83ee1fe:c0db1933d3c240078a2556758ddd6841)<br/>
[09:00:14] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4<br/>
intel_do_flush_locked failed: Input/output error
```

OS: Xubuntu 14.04.2
I already tried the one provided in the link. My current GPU for this PC is Intel Q35 and there are no additional proprietary drivers.

Outputs:https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W15d.jpg

Comment: This is a bit old to be considered an exact duplicate, but may be useful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/170668/intel-do-flush-locked-failed-input-output-error

Comment: From a little research, I've found that this is a driver crash. Are there any proprietary drivers in the Additional Drivers app?

Comment: Please [edit] your post and include the output of `uname -a` , `lsb_release -a` and `sudo lshw -C video`

Comment: Do you have Java 6 or 7 installed?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Usually restarting the computer does the trick. However ￼￼

`LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 java -jar Minecraft.jar`

works, but my FPS goes down from 0-23 to 1-3.Thus, the game isn't really playable this way.