# Error while playing Steam games: intel_do_flush_locked failed: Input/output error

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics

I have a (pretty much) fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 and am getting the following error when launching Starbound:

```
intel_do_flush_locked failed: Input/output error
```

Starbound has always worked great for me before on 14.04 and 16.10, but I cannot get it to work on 16.04. By using this command:

```
LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 ./run-client.sh
```

I can get the game to start, but it runs waaay to slow. I am using a laptop with an i7 for my graphics, and all other games I've tried run no problemo, so I'm a bit confused why I'm getting this issue.

Thank you for any help!

EDIT:
I thought the issue might have been that I used the Linux Intel Graphics Update tool, and so I reinstalled my system. I am now using a brand-new installation of Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop with an Core i7, using Intel integrated graphics for hardware acceleration. Every other game I've tried runs fine, and I do know that the issue is not with Starbound as the game has run fine on Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.10. I am at an utter loss as to why I would get this issue.

EDIT 2:
After checking my syslog, I noticed these error messages coming up:

```
[drm] GPU HANG: ecode 9:0:0x85dffffb, in starbound [19542], reason: Hang on render ring, action: reset
[drm] RC6 on
[drm] GuC firmware load skipped
drm/i915: Resetting chip after gpu hang
drm] RC6 on
[drm] GuC firmware load skipped
```

Comment: is this ubuntu based steam or wine based steam?

Comment: It is regular Steam from apt.

Comment: sorry, it is beyond my knowledge then

Comment: Related: [intel_do_flush_locked failed Input/Output error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170668/intel-do-flush-locked-failed-input-output-error) (But setting `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1` won't really work for you, since you probably plan to play games that really do need to use the GPU.)

Comment: Ok, well, a month later Starbound is suddenly working again. No idea why; my best bet/hope is that the developers fixed this issue and it will never plague anyone again. But just a guess.